# How to get csrf token from another website?

Tags: python, python-requests

How would I go about getting the csrf token from roblox.com? I need to use it for a group bot. I'm having trouble getting it. Also, once I get it, how would I go about actually posting it via `requests.post()`? I'm thinking about something along of lines of the following:

```
requests.post("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login"), data=data, {['X-CSRF-TOKEN']=token})
```

Comment: Umm... does that request succeed (without the header which invalid syntax) eg: it returns a 200 response? If that works... check the `.headers` of the response to see if it's there, failing that check the `.cookies` of the response... and failing that you'll have to parse the content of the response somehow to see if it's there.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. However, I'm still having a bit of trouble with actually posting the request. I edited my code after looking further into the topic.
`headers = {"X-CSRFToken": p.headers["x-csrf-token"]}
 r = requests.post("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login", data=datamain, headers=headers)`
Regardless of what I'm doing, I'm only getting a 403 response; not a 200 response.

Comment: You're sending a header of `X-CSRFToken` instead of `x-csrf-token` - note the hyphen?

Comment: Ah. My bad. As you can probably tell, I'm new to this whole thing.  Thanks for your assistance!